# How to replace wildcards in Bash variables?

Tags: bash

I have following variable:

```
$var="123#10.20.30.40.50"
```

I need replace dots in variable and skip `123#` substring. I expect result as:

```
echo $var
10 20 30 40 50
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# Must be 'var', not '$var' for assignment
var="123#10.20.30.40"
echo "${var}"

# Expand var, remove matching prefix pattern '*\#' (up to first '#')
var=${var#*\#}
echo "${var}"

# Expand var, pattern substitution '\.' with ' ' for ALL matches
var=${var//\./ }
echo "${var}"
```

Output:

```
123#10.20.30.40
10.20.30.40
10 20 30 40
```

Documentation on this and more available by `man bash`, chapter "Parameter Expansion".

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

```
$ echo "$var" | cut -d '#' -f2 | sed 's,\., ,g'
10 20 30 40 50
```